# layout_toRightOf: String types not allowed

Tags: java, android, layout

I have the following controls: ListView and Two TextView's inside a row.

I'm trying to make the 'rowTextView' stand on the left and 'rowTextCount' right next to it on the right.

Here's my xml for the row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.k.l.MainActivity" >

<com.k.l.MyTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
     android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:padding="5dp"  
     android:textColor="#888"
     android:textSize="28sp" >  
</com.k.l.MyTextView>  

<com.k.l.MyTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
     android:id="@+id/rowTextCount"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:padding="5dp"  
     android:textColor="#888"
     android:layout_toRightOf="rowTextView"
     android:text="666"
     android:textSize="28sp" >  
</com.k.l.MyTextView>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_toRightOf' with value 'rowTextView')

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is expecting and `id`. Change it to:

```
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rowTextView"
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_toRightOf) you can find the documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
 <com.k.l.MyTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
     android:id="@+id/rowTextCount"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:padding="5dp"  
     android:textColor="#888"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowTextView"
     android:text="666"
     android:textSize="28sp" >  
</com.k.l.MyTextView>
```